# Field extensions of the real numbers having degree 2

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, real-numbers

Suppose that $k$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that has degree $2$. What is a simple, direct argument (not involving deep results of field theory) to see that there is $x\in k$ with $x^2+1=0$? I want to show that any $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of dimension 2 that is a field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is not true that every $\Bbb R$-algebra of dimension 2 is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$ since such an algebra need not be a field. For instance, $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ with component-wise multiplication is such an $\Bbb R$-algera.

Comment: @AlexG. thanks, I wanted to include the condition that it be a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is of the form $\mathbb{R[x]}/(x^2+ax+b)$ for some irreducible monic polynomial of degree $2$. For this, just take $\alpha\in k\setminus\mathbb{R}$ and notice that $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$ are $\mathbb{R}$-dependent because the degree of the extension is $2$. Now, after a traslaton of the polynomial we can assume that $a=0$ and then we have a root of $x^2+b=0$ with $b>0$. Dividing such root by $\sqrt{b}$ (which is in $\mathbb{R}$ we get a root of $-1$.

Comment: Are $\mathbb{R}$-*dependent*.